# Plaster ceiling veneer coat issue

Tags: drywall, plaster

I had some chipping in my plaster ceiling. I used a paint scraper to take off the loose stuff, but the problem quickly grew. The veneer that came off from scraping is maybe a 1/32” thick. The actual plaster seems to be in good shape and not separating from the lathe.

What is the best way to repair this “veneer coat?” I was going to mix 45min mud and lay on a coat. Maybe some adhesion promoter on the bare plaster first?

Any input is appreciated.
[image: Ceiling photo]

Comment: There are dozens of ways to fix this when a buddy and I flipped a few places we did use hot mud but added a little sand to it so it would look the same, I don’t usually recommend hot mud for rookies as they tend to over work it.  If you use 45 minute start a timer when the water hits the mud and finish working it in 20-25 minutes. If you add sand put it in first not a lot 1/4-1/2 cup will be enough for a mud pan and it looks like that’s about what you need,

Comment: The part of the ceiling that is in good condition has a surface finish similar to painted drywall, so I will omit the sand. I am going to go with my original plan, but with a 90min mud based on your caution about 45min.

Answer (score -1):

I have what looks like a very similar situation, including very thin plaster over the lath.  I haven't solved it yet.  Below video is one I've found that might be helpful.  Of particular note, he uses a bonding agent on the wood lath.  (PlasterWeld in this case, but he says elsewhere that such as Quikrete concrete bonder will do as well.)

He has a lot of videos.  I think they're worth watching.  He does sometimes use (setting type) joint compound, as you propose ... maybe just on repairs?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8RrBi3LJEE

Comment: The video is good but represents a complete tear down of old plaster. My plaster is still securely attached to the lathe - just the thin veneer coat is failing.

Comment: The video may be good, but links, especially on YouTube, die. Please [edit] to include some salient tips from the video so this answer is useful even without the video.